# 3D Inverted structure

Tags: texturing, materials, modifiers, 3d-view

[image: Inverse opal structure created from a pack of spheres]

Hello,
I want to create an inverse opal structure using Blender similar to the one posted here and put some nanoparticles inside. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: but i am still not sure why my picture is still looking pretty different to your image - aren't the "holes" in the structure not perfect spheres?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use geometry nodes for this:

[image]

be careful: GN needs some time to calculate the boolean result, so be patient.

result:

[image]

[image]

NOTE: i started with a cube of these dimensions:

[image]

result, if you put 0.5 in z translation of transform geometry:

[image]

---

update: now with inner sphere:

[image]

[image]

---

Update 2: of course Vklidu's idea was way better in performance than mine, so if you do the boolean mesh before, it's much quicker:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much Chris. I will give it a shot :)

Comment: @Chris Crossed in time&space :) BTW since boolean operation. is slow I wanted to switch order [to boolean Sphere from Cube and instance on a Grid](https://imgur.com/ZBxf2I6), that was way faster, but since OP-reference is cut at specific place it required one more boolean at the end  - so it didn't avoid heavy boolean math ... hm

Comment: Any idea how to add spherical particles inside?

Comment: i updated my answer