# How can we create this gold nanoparticles structure?

Tags: geometry-nodes, workflow, geometry, volumetrics

How can we create the molecular structure (AuNPs) below?

Using a volume cube can be a solution but I couldn't achieve it properly.

Kindly help

[image: molecular reference image]

Comment: Isn't this question about a [3d inverted structure](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/281972/3d-inverted-structure) the same question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a "grid cube" here i use the cube it self to create a plane and a line, i subdivide them by the same amount and i instance the plane on the line:

[image]

Then I realize the instances in order to instance each point of the "grid cube" of course those instances are spheres.
Then I use a boolean (but you have to realize the spheres before) on the first cube that I have scaled a bit.

[image]

**Edit:**
For the gold particles to be placed out of the surface we have to displace the particle by an amount equal to  the particles radius. Then it's pretty straight forward:

[image]

If that not do the trick there is another hack.

I hope it help.

The new .blend

[image]

Comment: This is a nice approach. How can we add spheres inside these cavities randomly ?